# ReSharper: Null check is always false warning

Tags: c#, generics, resharper

Using ReSharper 8.2 I get a warning ("Expression is always false") for the null check in

```
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
  if (key == null)
```

from [NHibernate NullableDictionary](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Util/NullableDictionary.cs). Why is this? When I try it with

```
class Test<T> where T : class
```

then I don't get the warning for null checks on T variables as expected.

**Edit:** To make things easier here is the class signature of the linked source:

```
public class NullableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue> where TKey : class
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's occurring because the class implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`; the warning disappears if you (temporarily) delete the interface portion of the class signature.

Since the "key" in the standard `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` class can never be `null` (it throws an `ArgumentNullException`), I'd say ReSharper is making an incorrect assumption.

---

**Testing the behavior:**

I tested the class in an otherwise empty project and tried it out. Although ReSharper grayed out all the code, it definitely still executed at runtime.

The gray text indicates ReSharper believes the logic will *always* drop through to the `else` block, but that's clearly not the case when you use it.

[image]

---

**A fix, using Annotations:**

To get around the issue of ReSharper assuming by default that the key cannot be `null`, you could use the JetBrains Annotations.

Add a reference to the JetBrains Annotations assembly. For me, this was the location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\Bin\JetBrains.Annotations.dll

Then add a using directive to the top of the file where the class is:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
```

Now mark that parameter with the `CanBeNull` attribute and you'll see ReSharper no longer grays out the text:

```
public bool TryGetValue([CanBeNull] TKey key, out TValue value)
```

[image]

Comment: But in a NullableDictionary it can. So I guess ReSharper expects that an implemetor of IDictionary sticks to the principle that at runtime the key must not be null.

Comment: The fix is very nice. Also now I think that the ReSharper assumption is correct because the docs for IDictionary<TKey, TValue> state that ArgumentNullException will be thrown for null keys.